# Exception starting IPython notebook

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook

When I start an ipython notebook as follows:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Python27\scripts\ipython-script.py" notebook
```

I get the following errors:

```
2014-07-24 14:22:24.584 [NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'C:\\Users\\psmith\\.ipython\\profile_default'
2014-07-24 14:22:24.595 [NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
2014-07-24 14:22:24.618 [NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\loshea\TFS\Research
2014-07-24 14:22:24.618 [NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
2014-07-24 14:22:24.618 [NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
2014-07-24 14:22:24.618 [NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
ERROR:root:Exception in I/O handler for fd 648
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pyzmq-2.2.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 346, in start
    self._handlers[fd](fd, events)
KeyError: 648L
```

and the error is then repeated endlessly.  My config is (python from [python.org](http://python.org) and all packages from [Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)'s site):

- Python 2.7.8 (64-bit)
- ipython-2.1.0
- pyzmq-14.3.1
- certifi-14.05.14
- backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2
- tornado-4.0

Any idea what I'm doing wrong wrong?

Comment: I created a virtualenv and installed some packages using (using `pip install` rather than CG's packages).  Now executing `ipython notebook` seems to work fine.  `pip freeze` reports Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
certifi==14.05.14
ipython==2.1.0
pyreadline==2.0
pyzmq==14.3.1
tornado==4.0. This not a full solution, since I would like to be able to use a notebook from outside a virtual environment.

Comment: I created a virtualenv with --system-site-packages.  Then from inside the venv I installed ipython and ran `ipython notebook`. This generated the errors as before.

Comment: Removing everything (namely all packages and python itself) followed by reinstalling python and the needed packages via pip seemed to get it to work.

Comment: Also, installing all the necessary packages from CG's site also results in a working installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best as I can make out my python configuration was in some bad state that was not fixed by upgrading single packages.  However a full reinstall (see comments to my question) seemed to fix the problem.  Also, since in trying to debug this I found that the `ipython notebook` worked in a virtual environment.  I did not consider this a full solution because I typically needed binary packages (from Christoph Gohlke's site) which would then not be available in the venv.  However, I then found the following blog post, which make venvs much more useful under Windows: http://www.philipsouthwell.com/blog/create-a-virtual-environment-with-windows/.  In case the above link disappears, it boils down to this: you can download one of the CG packages (which is an EXE) and then install it from inside the venv by using `easy_install`.